# Maven2 + Distributed build on slave.

Tags: maven, hudson, distributed

I experiencing an issue when tried to build a project on a slave. 
I've got a pom.xml with something like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
    author: xxx
    version: $Id$
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>website-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx-web</artifactId>
    <name>${pom.artifactId}</name>
    <description>xxx web application</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>2.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <package.installdir>/var/goom/www/xxx.com/${package.target}/ROOT</package.installdir>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:https://xxx/svn/v3/code/websites/com/main/trunk</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://xxx/svn/v3/code/websites/com/main/trunk</developerConnection>
        <url>https://xxx/svn/v3/code/websites/com/main/trunk</url>
    </scm>

</project>
```

The build work's very well on the master, however on the slave there is a problem to reach the parent :

```
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.xxx:website-parent:pom:1.0.4' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: com.xxx:xxx-barbershop:pom:2.1.2-SNAPSHOT

Reason: Cannot find parent: com.xxx:website-parent for project: com.xxx:xxx-barbershop:pom:2.1.2-SNAPSHOT for project com.xxx:xxx-barbershop:pom:2.1.2-SNAPSHOT
```

Do i need to configure something on the slave to handle with the parent defined on the master ? 
( I'm not an maven expert ... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the parent project in the slave's local repo, like with `mvn install` on the parent project.

Comment: Well i think ur absolutely right but i dont't know how to make that tricks :D I tried something like this : mvn install website-parent but i'm stuck !

Comment: Ok i answer to myself ... i needed to configure both settings.xml file and security-settings.xml ( caused by encrypted password ) And it seems to work fine.